# Schedule an Email and create send definition via REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, api, send-an-email

I have an email in "Content Builder" (This email created using the API).

This email should be sent via API.

How can I create an API Call:

1. create a send definition.
2. Schedule an Email and send it to DE / Data
   filter.

Comment: You will need to use soap to accomplish this

Comment: How can I do that?